# Autoit Date reformat

Tags: autoit, data-conversion

I have a variable that holds a string representing a date.

```
$d = "March 17,2019"
```

Actually, my code doesn't set d's value like that, but for arguments sake, lets assume that d holds a string date in the format shown.

Is there an easy way to change that d$ string to be in the following format instead: mm/dd/yy format?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One more Basic code for your reference

```
$d1 = "March 17,2019"
$year=StringRight($d1,2) ; if you want like 2019 use StringRight($d1,4)
$rightstr = StringLeft($d1,(StringLen($d1)-5))
$test = StringSplit($rightstr, " ")
$mon = $test[1]
$day = $test[2]
Local $mon1
Local $aMMM[12] = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
for $i =0 to 11
    if $mon = $aMMM[$i] Then
        $mon1 = $i+1
    EndIf
Next
$mon1= StringFormat("%02d", $mon1)
$finaldate = $day&"/"&$mon1&"/"&$year
MsgBox(1,"",$finaldate)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$d = "March 17,2019"

$sFormattedDate = _MyDate($d)

If Not @error Then
    MsgBox(0, @ScriptName, $sFormattedDate)
EndIf

Func _MyDate($sDate, $iYearLen = 4)
    ; Get month, day and year from a string (3 = return array of global matches).
    $aDate = StringRegExp($sDate, '(\w+)\s+(\d{1,2}),(\d{4})', 3)

    If UBound($aDate) = 3 Then
        ; Create an array of months.
        $aMonths = StringSplit('January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December', '|')

        ; Match month and return in mm/dd/yy format.
        For $i1 = 1 To UBound($aMonths) -1
            If $aDate[0] = $aMonths[$i1] Then
                If $iYearLen <> 4 Then
                    $aDate[2] = StringRight($aDate[2], $iYearLen)
                EndIf

                Return StringFormat('%02d/%02d/%d', $i1, $aDate[1], $aDate[2])
            EndIf
        Next
    EndIf

    ; Return error 1 if month is not matched.
    Return SetError(1, 0, '')
EndFunc
```

Uses a regular expression to get month, day and year from the date string.
If the month is matched from an array of months, then the array index of
the month is used in [StringFormat](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/StringFormat.htm) instead.
This will return `03/17/2019` from `March 17,2019` in the example code.
If `_MyDate()` fails, `@error` is set to the value of `1`.

[StringFormat](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/StringFormat.htm) uses `%02d/%02d/%d` on each date segment which forces a
zero padding of 2 digits for month and day. If the zero padding is not
needed then remove the `02` between `%` and `d`.

If you want the year to be only 2 digits, then use `2` as the 2nd
parameter of `_MyDate()`.

E.g.

```
$sFormattedDate = _MyDate($d, 2)
```

The pattern in [StringRegExp](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/StringRegExp.htm) uses:

- `\w` to match a word character.
- `\d` to match a digit.
- `\s` to match a space.

Parentheses are used to get the 3 segments from the date string.

---

If you want to keep the month as is, and just replace the space and
the comma with a `/`.

```
$d = "March 17,2019"

$sFormattedDate = StringRegExpReplace($d, '[\s,]', '/')
MsgBox(0, @ScriptName, $sFormattedDate)
```